# ASP.NET Data Caching? Memcache equivalent

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, caching, memcached

Having used PHP on Linux a lot, I'm used to using memcache so that the database doesnt have to be accessed on every single request. What do people use on Windows the achieve this? From the asp.net mvc applications which I've seen, none of them use any sort of cache, they just hit the database on every request? Is this common, and if so, why is it acceptable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [memcached](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19789/Memcached-Distributed-Cache-ASP-net-Provider) also. There are also [other alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_(memory_cache)). You may also check Scott Gu's [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) about the new cache extensibility model introduced in ASP.NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Memcache equivalent for ASP.NET, it is AppFabric (code name Velocity). You can find out how to install and use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx), there are also detail instruction and whitepapers.

Comment: Be aware that every node in an AppFabric caching cluster must be running Windows Server Enterprise Edition. This greatly increases the cost of choosing AppFabric over Memcache.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr That is not correct since october 2012. Here you have a post in which its support for windows server 2012 standard was communicated. Also windows server 2008 is supported. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/workflowteam/archive/2012/10/25/appfabric-now-supported-on-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: @Tien-Do Instead of using Memcache, could I use Microsoft AppFabric Caching for communication between PHP and ASP.NET? Will Microsoft AppFabric Caching work with PHP? If yes, how well does Microsoft AppFabric Caching work with PHP?

Comment: @user1338998 Sorry I have no information on PHP since I've never worked with PHP. But like other MS frameworks I don't think it has API for PHP, you'd better to check MS site for detail information.

Answer (score 2):

Very few professionally built mvc apps would 'hit the database on every request', mvc is still built on top of the asp.net infrastructure which has a robust and proven cacheing engine.

FYI: Microsoft's memcache equivalent is called Velocity
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/velocity/

Comment: +1 for "Very few professionally built mvc apps would 'hit the database on every request"

Comment: "mvc is still built on top of the asp.net infrastructure which has a robust and proven cacheing engine." Any more details on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Memcache on Windows as well. A very good version of Memcache is available from [Northscale](http://info.northscale.com/Memcached.html).