# Application Cache and Slow Process

Tags: asp.net, caching, webforms

I want to create an application wide feed on my ASP.net 3.5 web site using the application cache.  The data that I am using to populate the cache is slow to obtain, maybe up to 10 seconds (from a remote server's data feed).  My question/confusion is, what is the best way to structure the cache management.

```
private const string CacheKey = "MyCachedString";
private static string lockString = "";

public string GetCachedString()
{
    string data = (string)Cache[CacheKey];
    string newData = "";

    if (data == null)
    {
        // A - Should this method call go here?
        newData = SlowResourceMethod();

        lock (lockString)
        {
            data = (string)Cache[CacheKey];

            if (data != null)
            {
               return data;
            }

            // B - Or here, within the lock?
            newData = SlowResourceMethod();
            Cache[CacheKey] = data = newData;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

The actual method would be presented by and HttpHandler (.ashx).

If I collect the data at point 'A', I keep the lock time short, but might end up calling the external resource many times (from web pages all trying to reference the feed).  If I put it at point 'B', the lock time will be long, which I am assuming is a bad thing.

What is the best approach, or is there a better pattern that I could use?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity why aren't you using a prebuilt caching solution like memcached or similar? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667433/asp-net-data-caching-memcache-equivalent)

Comment: I had simply not come across prebuilt caching solutions, but I will investigate - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the comments on the code.

```
private const string CacheKey = "MyCachedString";
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();

public string GetCachedString()
{
    string data = (string)Cache[CacheKey];
    string newData = "";

    // start to check if you have it on cache
    if (data == null)
    {
        // A - Should this method call go here?
        // absolut not here
        // newData = SlowResourceMethod();

        // we are now here and wait for someone else to make it or not
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            // now lets see if some one else make it...
            data = (string)Cache[CacheKey];

            // we have it, send it
            if (data != null)
            {
               return data;
            }

            // not have it, now is the time to look for it.
            // B - Or here, within the lock?
            newData = SlowResourceMethod();
            // set it on cache
            Cache[CacheKey] = data = newData;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Better for me is to use `mutex` and lock depended on the name `CacheKey` and not lock all resource and the non relative one. With mutex one basic simple example will be:

```
private const string CacheKey = "MyCachedString";
public string GetCachedString()
{
    string data = (string)Cache[CacheKey];
    string newData = "";

    // start to check if you have it on cache
    if (data == null)
    {
        // lock it base on resource key 
        //  (note that not all chars are valid for name)
        var mut = new Mutex(true, CacheKey);

        try
        {   
            // Wait until it is safe to enter.
            // but also add 30 seconds max
            mut.WaitOne(30000);

            // now lets see if some one else make it...
            data = (string)Cache[CacheKey];

            // we have it, send it
            if (data != null)
            {
               return data;
            }

            // not have it, now is the time to look for it.
            // B - Or here, within the lock?
            newData = SlowResourceMethod();
            // set it on cache
            Cache[CacheKey] = data = newData;

        }
        finally
        {
            // Release the Mutex.
            mut.ReleaseMutex();
        }    
    }

    return data;
}
```

You can also read
[Image caching issue by using files in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554928/image-caching-issue-by-using-files-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thank you Aristos.  Your answer was comprehensive and easy to understand - much appreciated.